# I received a "correct answer" mark, but I didn't receive any rep for it.

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

I'm at the rep cap for today, but getting an answer marked as correct shouldn't be influenced by the rep cap?

The item appears in my "Answers" section as green, meaning it was selected as correct, but it doesn't show up at all in my reputation list.

Is this by design or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you referring to your [most recent accepted answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/how-do-you-know-whether-a-game-is-in-the-public-domain/1006#1006)?

It is marked as [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts). Those questions and answers will not earn you reputation.